# How to use Gtk::EntryCompletion::set_match_func on GTKMM C++?

Tags: c++, linux, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm

i want to search something for every sub string. I've been looking for GTK completion example on internet but i couldn't find the example with set_match_func. The documentation says i need to specify SlotMatch, but I don't understand how to use SlotMatch.

```cpp
  m_completion->set_text_column(0);
  m_completion->set_minimum_key_length(0);
  m_completion->set_popup_completion(true);
  m_completion->set_match_func(func);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line in the documentation, right after the inheritance diagram

```
typedef sigc::slot< bool(const Glib::ustring&, const TreeModel::const_iterator&)>   SlotMatch;
```

Further reading reaches the example

> For example, `bool on_match(const Glib::ustring& key, const TreeModel::const_iterator& iter);`

In gtkmm

```
m_completion->set_match_func(sigc::ptr_fun(on_match));
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It's available inside the header file, i didn't see that.